# Terraform Azurerm - Data Export Rule

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-eventhub, azure-log-analytics

My query is related to azurerm_log_analytics_data_export_rule. I have created Log Analytics Workspace and Eventhub in portal followed all the steps in below link.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_data_export_rule

Both Terraform Plan and Apply are successful. But the expected tables are not created in Eventhub. For example (as per above link) “Heartbeat” table is not created Eventhub after export_rule created. The below Microsoft documentation mentions that the tables will be automatically created in EH or Storage account once export rule creation successful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal

Will be helpful if I get some info on this rule.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Hashicrop](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_data_export_rule)** template you are following will create new resource group, storage account, log analytics workspace & a export rule.

- Since the above terraform template is creating  new environment & there will be no heart beat logs present by default so that is reason why there were no heart beat logs container was created.
- When we have tested in our environment,  exporting heart beat logs of log analytics workspace data to storage account it took nearly 30 minutes to get the data to be reflected in our storage account.

### [Data completeness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=azure-cli#data-completeness)

Data export will continue to retry sending data for up to 30 minutes in the event that the destination is unavailable. If it's still unavailable after 30 minutes then data will be discarded until the destination becomes available.

Comment: Hi Venkatesh, thanks for your response. I have shared my code in this conversation (ignore storage account resource as I am trying to send data from SA to LAW first). The export rule should help to send mentioned tables data from LAW to EH. Let me know if this creates tables in EH successfully.

Comment: @user2913892 - I had setup the same configuration in our environment when i enable the diagnostic settings for blob in a storage account to log analytics workspace. Those are logs getting recorded in 'Storagebloblogs' table in log analytics work space.

Comment: We have tired exporting the "usage" table to event hub it took nearly 30 minutes here is screenshot of reference output.
https://imgur.com/WIK4APj

Based on the azure documentation,'storage blob logs'(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-data-export?tabs=portal) table is not present in the supported listed & exporting of logs storage logs from log analytics workspace to event hub wont be possible.

Answer (score 0):

````
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "data_export_resource_group" {
  name     = "test_data_export_rg"
  location = "centralus"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "data_export_log_analytics_workspace" {
  name                = "testdataexportlaw"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "data_export_azurerm_storage_account" {
  name                     = "testdataexportazurermsa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "data_export_azurerm_eventhub_namespace" {
  name                = "testdataexportehnamespace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 1

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub" "data_export_eventhub" {
  name                = "testdataexporteh1"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.data_export_azurerm_eventhub_namespace.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.name
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1
}

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_data_export_rule" "example" {
  name                    = "testdataExport1"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.data_export_resource_group.name
  workspace_resource_id   = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.data_export_log_analytics_workspace.id
  destination_resource_id = azurerm_eventhub.data_export_eventhub.id
  table_names             = ["Usage","StorageBlobLogs"]
  enabled                 = true
} 
```
````

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.